# What is the abbreviation for Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I was thinking it could be ADO, but that would get it confused with a legacy Microsoft data access layer "ActiveX Data Objects" or whatever it stood for... Or DevOps, but that would get it confused with devops in general, and it's not all that much shorter anyway... Is there an official abbreviation or one that has been settled on by the community?

Comment: This question is still relevant today and without a good answer. After TFS, VSO and VSTS, Microsoft didn't leave us with any good choice for internal abbreviation. We keep using _TFS_ now, as many internal tools and links still use this abbreviation.

Comment: @djk Agreed, nobody likes to type it out in chats every time. We recently decided to go with "AzDO" for typing, which could also be pronounced "As Doe", however, we try to say "AzureDevOps" when speaking.

Answer (score 17):

I've seen 'AzDO' used with success and am not aware of any existing conflicts, like with the misused 'ADO' acronym.

Answer (score 8):

From MVP [Juan Rafael](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/5001496?fullName=Juan%20Rafael), as per [this slide presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/jmfabian/azure-devops-136808173) which seems fairly definitive, [slide 43](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/azuredevops-190317040637/95/azure-devops-43-638.jpg?cb=1552796090) states:

> No abbreviations should be used (especially not ADS). Azure DevOps or #AzureDevOps are the only permitted forms.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know there is no official abbreviation for Azure DevOps, these are the ones i tend to hear:  ADO, ADOPS, VSTS (yep still going strong). but the majority of times i see people just spelling it out fully.

But i'll keep an eye on this thread to see if there will be some consensus reached :P

Comment: Agree with Remco, Azure DevOps don't have an official abbreviation at present. And VSTS is the abbreviation of Visual Studio Team Services, VSTS is the predecessor of Azure DevOps. So sometimes people always use VSTS to represent Azure DevOps, but actually there are some ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer ADO over AZDO/AzDO. It should be clear enough of what you're talking based on the general context of your conversations (Cloud vs. . Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX_Data_Objects, ADO.NET is the current technology, so ADO is available again ;-)

Comment: ADO has changed to ADO.NET and ADO Classic. As you said, depends on context. In conversation, I always use ADO.NET and ADO Classic. In development, just ADO. I don't want non-developers to search on ADO and find ADO Classic references.

Comment: I wouldn't say ADO is "available again" per se. Just as .NET previously was a catch-all term for .NET Framework and .NET Core, I'd say ADO is a catch-all term for ADO.NET and ADO Classic.