# Git: Keep all branches up to date

Tags: git, jenkins, synchronization, git-pull

guys!
I've got recently a DevOp position on a small company and one of my first tasks sound like this:

> Most usual scenario is that a dev works on a branch, then switches
> branch to do a hotfix and forgets to do a git pull before making
> changes or before creating a new branch off that particular branch.

I would like to know how can I reach that goal, to sync their work in case of forgetting to use `git pull` by one of our devs.

- We're using Jenkins if it can help us to reach our goal.

Thank you!

Comment: Add a cron to do `git fetch`  and add a pre hook to check if is up to date on local. You cannot pull in background you can have conflict

Comment: Unless you're committing directly to a branch, I strongly advocate against ever checking it out, and I also suggest deleting local copies of shared branches as soon as you're done with them. For creating new branches and updating it with merge or rebase, I [recommend using origin instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71057049/184546).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you're looking for is git hooks
from GIT [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

> Like many other Version Control Systems, Git has a way to fire off custom scripts when certain important actions occur. There are two groups of these hooks: client-side and server-side. Client-side hooks are triggered by operations such as committing and merging, while server-side hooks run on network operations such as receiving pushed commits. You can use these hooks for all sorts of reasons.

for your use case, I think the best one is to use the **post-checkout** hook

so when someone switch or do a checkout a bash script will run

to test this, go to a git folder and run

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > .git/hooks/post-checkout
echo "echoed by git hook" >> .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

make the file executable

```
chmod+x .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

and try to switch to a branch, you'll see the content "echoed by git hook" displayed